# is it possible to get my fb wall entries in my website database ?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to have my or someone else facebook wall entries (only posts , no comment or pictures ) in my website database ..... i've been reading around but i couldn't find much .

so i wonder if it is possible at all ?  i've gone as far as login in to app and retriving access token

```
require '../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '3333',
  'secret' => 'xxxxx',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_284654551659478_access_token'] ;
}
```

what now ? i cant find anything in fb document about retriving user entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout Facebook Graph Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Use: `me?fields=posts`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using graph API,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{SOME_USER_NAME}/feed?access_token={SOME_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Comment: i need user entries , feed wouldn't get me that